# Ada95 Loop through Array within a Record and print the characters

Tags: ada

The program below is suppose to get an input of Characters from the user and put it into an Record with the subprogram **Procedure Get(Tecken : out Record_Type)**. The last step is to Print it in the Terminal with another subprogram **Procedure Put(Chars : in Chars_Array)**.

The issue I'm facing is the actual output of the Characters into the Terminal where I get:

[Picture of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVdzG.png)

```
procedure Poster is

type Char_Array is                            -- Fält/Array
    array (1..256) of Character;

type Record_Type is                           -- Post/Record
    record
        Chars : Char_Array;
        Length : Integer;
    end record;
```

---

```
procedure Get(Tecken : out Record_Type) is   -- Character input

begin

    for I in 1..256 loop
        Get(Tecken.Chars(I));
        exit when End_Of_Line;
    end loop;

end Get;
```

---

Here is the subprogram that prints the Characters from the Array. I'm confused when it comes to Records and Arrays, but I'm thinking that I need an Array as a inparameter since I can't loop through Records.

```
procedure Put(Chars : in  Char_Array) is   -- Character output

begin

    for I in 1..256 loop
        Put(Chars(I));
    end loop;

end Put;
```

---

Here is another bump in the road where I use an inparameter "Chars" the Put-Call. Does the Char_Array recognize the input in "Tecken" ?

```
Tecken : Record_Type;
Chars : Char_Array; 

begin

    Get(Tecken);
    Put(Chars);

end Poster;
```

Comment: Do you fill out all the positions in `Tecken.Chars` in procedure `Get`?

Comment: It all depends on the user. I've added "exit when End_Of_Line;" to determine if there is an Enter pressed. I have only tried random input such as "asdfg" to se what output I recieve.

Comment: In what way do you ensure that you don't attempt to output more with `Put` than what was read by `Get`?

Comment: This looks liike you really want to use `Ada.Strings.Bounded` with a `Max` of 256.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a bit of a warning from the compiler:

```
poster.adb:31:04: warning: variable "Chars" is read but never assigned
```

This is because `Get` writes to `Tecken.Chars`; the `Chars` you pass to `Put` has nothing to do with it, and is filled with random data.

You say "I'm thinking that I need an Array as a inparameter since I can't loop through Records". True, you can’t loop through a record, but you can loop through an array that is part of a record.

If you say

```
Put(Tecken.Chars);
```

things work better, though you still get garbage after the actual input. You might expect even better if you say

```
   Put(Tecken.Chars (1 .. Tecken.Length));
```

but

```
$ ./poster 
0123456789

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : poster.adb:36 range check failed
```

which is because `Get` doesn’t actually set `Tecken.Length`.

After fixing this[*], this should do the trick

```
procedure Put (Tecken : in  Record_Type) is
begin
   for I in 1 .. Tecken.Length loop
      Put (Tecken.Chars(I));
   end loop;
end Put;
```

Now, the call is just

```
Put (Tecken);
```

[*] It’s not as easy to fix `Get` as you might hope, since when `End_Of_Line` is true the character returned is the last one on the line.

Comment: When I add Put(Tecken.Chars(1..Tecken.Length)) to the call, and the subprogram to "procedure Put(Tecken : in Record_Type) is 
begin

Comment: Ignore the above comment. I added the things to told me to in both the Call and inside the subprogram but I get the Error-messages:

"expected type "Record_Type" defined at line 9"
"found type "Char_Array" defined at line 6"

The compiler is complaining about Record_Type, and Tecken.Chars is clearly a Record_Type, or am I wrong?

Comment: After altering the definition of `Put`, the call should just be `Put (Tecken);`. `Tecken` is a `Record_Type`, and `Tecken.Chars` is a `Char_Array`.